# how to find self signed certificate

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, web, certificate

I'm confused about website certificate verification.  Please see details below:

Connection to the website(www.bitstamp.net) with python urllib2 threw:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>
```

curl gave a similar error:

```
$ curl https://www.bitstamp.net
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

However, openssl shows each certificate verified (assuming "1" means verified):

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.bitstamp.net:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = Hosted by Incapsula Inc, OU = PositiveSSL Multi-Domain, CN = incapsula.com
verify return:1
```

What's going on here?  Is there a "self signed certificate" as claimed by curl?  If so, which one?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you behind some kind of corporate proxy? Does your browser accept the certificate?

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Also, use the `-servername www.bitstamp.net` argument to `s_client` in order to use SNI and get the same certificate as curl and Python do.

Comment: It's interesting that this error only happened when I connected from google cloud vm instance.  Azsgy There is no proxy in my google cloud network settings.  @Steffen Ullrich adding -servername seems making difference:  depth=2 C = US, O = "Entrust, Inc.", OU = See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, OU = "(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", CN = Entrust Root Certification
 Authority - G2
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain        So this means I get difference certificate from google cloud which contains a self signed certificate I guess?

Comment: @LightningMcqueen: you get the expected certificates but in your first `s_client` test you did not use SNI. If the issue is only from google cloud the reason is probably that the trust store inside you google cloud system does not have the Entrust CA as trusted, for whatever reason this is.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich thanks, will looking into how that happened and re-install it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of symptoms of this behavior. Let’s start with first issue.

self-signed certificate in chain error: this is true and also a valid case. Because every root certificate authority is self-signed. In your case AddTrust is self-signed. This may indicate that certificate authorities are not recognized by curl/libssl or other client. As you said openssl s_client verified certificate. In many linux distros it is located under /etc/ssl/certs. Yours may be different or you may need to update them. You should also define location of these CAs to the library (even in libssl - SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations)

SNI based problem indicates that target server is serving multiple TLS/SSL based sites on the same host/ip. Without explicit SNI specification server is responding with any one (i am not sure about the selection algoritm, may be random or first one).

Both cases seem to be valid to me because of these reasons.